# Working with lots of dataframes/datasets/RDD in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Ok I'm relatively new to working with Scala/Spark and I'm wondering if there is a design pattern for working with lots of DataFrames (several 100k) in a Streaming app?

In my example I have a SparkStreaming app that has a message payload similar to:

```
{"user_id":123, "data":"ABC"}
{"user_id":456, "data":"DEF"}
{"user_id":123, "data":"GHI"}
```

So when a message comes in for a user_id:123 I need to pull in some external data using SparkSQL that is specific to the user in question and cache it locally then perform some additional computations and then persist new data to a DB. Then repeat the process for each message that comes in off the stream.

Now my question is, I would like to cache the data that gets pulled in for each user and then reuse the cached copy of the user's data (if it exists) each time I need to process a message from the stream for that user. I have millions of possible users with ~100K active at any given moment and I'll processing this data across several (~50-ish) executors.

I understand cached DataFrames/RDDs get LRU'd out of memory but, if I store each users cached computed data in map for quick lookup and retrieval locally on each executor such as:

```
Map[id: INT, user_data: DataFrame]
```

Would I be creating a scenario where I'm keeping around references to old DataFrames that will never get GC'd because I have active references to them and I'll eventually run out of memory?

Am I missing something fundamental here and there's a better more efficient method to achieve this?

Thanks, any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: ~100K `DataFrames` - that sounds like a really bad idea. To be more precise - using distributed data structures to store small chunks of data looks like a serious design mistake alone. These tools are designed to process massive data volumes not as a simple data access objects.

Comment: If the 100K objects have the same structure then you should use a single DataFrames of 100K items. If they don't have the same structure, then you need to change your design so they have the same structure.

Answer (score 0):

If the users meta data is static, I would simply keep a map with all user id and meta data and broadcast it to the workers. This is the best most efficient solution when you are dealing with a small map such as this. The harder case is when this "map" needs to be updated in time. In that case, I would load the data periodically into an rdd and continuously join it with the stream data as part of the pipeline.